# SQL read file, access denied error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bulk-load

I have the following SQL procedure:

```
   DECLARE @stament as nvarchar(max)

 set @stament='SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '''+ @Path+''', SINGLE_BLOB) MyFile '

EXECUTE sp_executesql    @stament
```

when I execute it, an error occurs:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\MyServer\New Folder" could not be
>   opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

I checked the permission on the folder, Everyone has full access, and the file exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is usually happens when SQL Server is not allowed to access the bulk load folder. Here is how to fix it: 
Go to the folder right click ->properties->Security tab->Edit->Add(on the new window) ->Advanced -> Find Now. Under the users list in the search results, find something like SQLServerMSSQLUser$UserName$SQLExpress and click ok, to all the dialogs opened.[image]

Also make sure that your user is bulkadmin:
[image]

Comment: I updated answer, try that one with bulkadmin option

Comment: Thank you for your help, when I test it on non-shared folder it works fine, but the error is for shared folder only.Regarding your suggestion, this works if i am not logging in using 'sa'

Comment: Try the solution from here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/bulk-insert-through-network